# Extra delimiter in MAC Address reformat

Tags: c#, regex

I've looked at several questions on here about formatting and validating MAC addresses, which is where I developed my regex from. The problem I'm having is that when I go to update the field is that there are extra delimiters in the new formatted MAC or if no delimiter exists the MAC fails to validate. I'm new to using regex, so can someone clarify why this is happening?

```
if (checkMac(NewMacAddress.Text) == true)
{
    string formattedMAC = NewMacAddress.Text;
    formattedMAC.Replace(" ", "").Replace(":", "").Replace("-", ""); //attempt to remove the delimiters before formatting
    var regex = "(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})";
    var replace = "$1:$2:$3:$4:$5:$6";
    var newformat = Regex.Replace(formattedMAC, regex, replace);
    NewMacAddress.Text = newformat.ToString();
}
```

Here is the checkmac function

```
protected bool checkMac(string macaddress)
    {
        macaddress.Replace(" ", "").Replace(":", "").Replace("-", "");
        Regex r = new Regex("^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$");

        if (r.Match(macaddress).Success)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

This is sample output for the extra delimiter that I was talking about. 00::5:0::56::b:f:00:7f
I was able to get the original MAC from a textbox. This also occurs with the MAC address I get from screen scrapes.

Comment: Your regex validation is requiring delimiters. If you don't to require it then remove the delimiter part of the regex.

Comment: How does that fix my formatting issue though? I don't care what format they provide me to validate, but I want to store a uniformed format of the MAC address...Thank you for pointing that out though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code is not working as intended is because:

1. [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not modify the string you pass in, but returns a new string instead (strings are [immutable](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/406046/Why-strings-are-immutable-and-what-are-the-implica)). You have to assign the result of `String.Replace` to a variable.
2. Your `checkMac` function only allows mac addresses with delimiters. You can simply remove this restriction to resolve your problems.

The working code then becomes something along the lines of:

```
string newMacAddress = "00::5:0::56::b:f:00:7f";
if (checkMac(newMacAddress) == true)
{
    string formattedMAC = newMacAddress;
    formattedMAC = formattedMAC.Replace(" ", "").Replace(":", "").Replace("-", ""); //attempt to remove the delimiters before formatting
    var regex = "(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})";
    var replace = "$1:$2:$3:$4:$5:$6";
    var newformat = Regex.Replace(formattedMAC, regex, replace);
    newMacAddress = newformat.ToString();
}

protected static bool checkMac(string macaddress)
{
    macaddress = macaddress.Replace(" ", "").Replace(":", "").Replace("-", "");
    Regex r = new Regex("^([0-9A-Fa-f]{12})$");

    if (r.Match(macaddress).Success)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close. I'm first going to answer using Ruby because that's what I'm most familiar with at the moment, and it should be sufficient for you to understand how to get it working in C#. Maybe I can convert it to C# later.

using these elements:

- `\A` - start of entire string
- `[0-9a-fA-F]` - any hex digit
- `{2}` - twice
- `[:-]?` - either ":" or "-" or "" (no delimiter)
- `\Z` - end of entire string, before ending newline if it exists
- `()` - parenthetical match in order to reference parts of the regex, e.g. `match[1]`

This regex will do what you need:

```
mac_address_regex = /\A([0-9a-fA-F]{2})[:-]?([0-9a-fA-F]{2})[:-]?([0-9a-fA-F]{2})[:-]?([0-9a-fA-F]{2})[:-]?([0-9a-fA-F]{2})[:-]?([0-9a-fA-F]{2})\Z/
```

You can both validate and sanitize input using this regex:

```
match = mac_address_regex.match(new_mac_address.text)
if match.present?
  sanitized_mac_addr = (1..6).map { |i| match[i] }.join(":") # join match[i] for i = (1,2,3,4,5,6)
  sanitized_mac_addr.upcase!                                 # uppercase
else
  sanitized_mac_addr = nil
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me understand more about regex and why mine was failing. I appreciate the extra explanation put into the answer.

Comment: Sure thing. If you found it useful, would you mind upvoting my answer? Thanks.

Comment: I need more rep to up vote, or else it would have been done already. I'm sorry.